# I was wondering if anyone can tell me how to understand the bytecode

Tags: java, bytecode

what is the meaning of this below bytecode

```
code:
0: aload_0
1: invokespecial #1;//Method Java/lang/Object."<init>":<u>;
4: return
```

Comment: Why you want to understand Bytecode?

Comment: perhaps you should go and read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html

Comment: Looks like the code of an empty constructor. `aload_0` loads the argument 0 object onto the stack, next it invokes the constructor of `Object` and lastly the method returns (nothing/`void`). Constructors are "special" methods under the hood and their name is `<init>` in stacktraces and so on. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings

Comment: Iam studying virtual machine(VM) architectures. I need to understand the Instruction Set Architecture (ISA) of VM. for that I need to Understand bytecode.

Answer (score 0):

0: Load memory slot 0 into the stack (slot 0 is usually "this" except in static methods)

1: invoke method referenced in constant pool #1 (The comment tells it is the default constructor of Object)

4: return

looks like the default constructor

Answer (score 0):

Refer the [JVM Specification Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/jvms7.pdf) to understand the bytecode syntax and semantics and how it is used by JVM.

Comment: Thanks I will go through it.

Comment: In the meanwhile, can you please suggest me some books on bytecode. I want to understand bytecode in detail. How is it generated and all the related stuff

Comment: Refer this bytecode guide which will fulfill most of your requirement I believe.

Comment: Of course, version 7 has been superseded by [version 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/jvms8.pdf).